# WorkFlow is not getting Executed

Tags: workflow

I am facing a rare scenario where Workflow is getting executed properly for One record and it is not getting executed for the Other record. PLease find the below logs, eventhough both of them are same, one is evalutated as true and another as false.

Log from One Record

17:16:48.643 (643642687)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Lead: duplicatetest7 duplicatetest7 00Q18000000u]|Update Lead Channel to Distributed|01Q13000000J|ON_ALL_CHANGES
17:16:48.643 (643803089)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull](  **Contains({!ID:00N18000000Nm}, "Distributed"))|Values:Owner_Role__c=Distributed Loan Officer Manager 4 RSM 2**
17:16:48.643 (643810711)|WF_CRITERIA_END|**true**

Log from another record.

03:46:59.064 (1064719794)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Lead: duplicatetest7 duplicatetest7 00Q18000000u]|Update Lead Channel to Distributed|01Q13000000J|ON_ALL_CHANGES
03:46:59.064 (1064806417)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull](  **Contains({!ID:00N18000000Nm}, "Distributed"))|Values:Owner_Role__c=Distributed Loan Officer Manager 4 RSM 2**
03:46:59.064 (1064811636)|WF_CRITERIA_END|**false**

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the actual workflow configuration?